# How I can access from directive to current value of some AngularJS model

Tags: angularjs

I have two inputs: input_1 and input_2. I type some value into input_1 and trying to access it when typing into input_2 (to use input_1 value for autocomplete input_2).

I've created directive:

```
.directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
        return function(scope, inputElement, inputAttrs) {    
                inputElement.autocomplete({
                    source: (function(){
                        var new_list = scope[inputAttrs.uiItems];
                        new_list.push(scope['input_one_value']);
                        return new_list
                    })(),
                    select: function() {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            inputElement.trigger('input');
                        }, 0);
                    }
                });
        };
    });
```

But with this approach inside directive I can access only initial value of model. How I can access to the current value of first input?

Comment: Using non-Angular widgets is just asking for a world of hurt. Also why reinvent the wheel, there are already plenty of Angular auto-complete widgets, such as : https://github.com/EnzeyNet/AutoComplete

Comment: Yep, but I am not familiar with AngularJS and wanted to use it as 'vanilla' as it possible. Just to get some experience before I start to use a lot of plugins and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass the first input value lie this:

```
.directive('something', function () {
  return {
    require: ['model'],
    scope: {
      'model': '=', // Two way data binding
    }
  };
})
```

And in the template pass the input1 value like this:

```
<some-tag model="model"></some-tag>
```

Then you will access to model inside your directive through scope, something like scope.model, which will be in sync with the current value.

Comment: With this way I only get "Controller 'user_input', required by directive 'input', can't be found!" error.